# .htaccess is not working in xampp (ubuntu)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu, xampp

I can't get **.htaccess** to work in **xampp** under **Ubuntu 13.04** and the server keep showing the 404 error page I tried to modify **httpd.conf** in /opt/lampp/apache2/conf/ with this code

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

but still give the same error page 
it looks like the server can't see the .htaccess file.
     What to do .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your htaccess file is in the right place (`/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs`) and that it is readable (`chmod 644 /opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/.htaccess`) and that the [access file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#accessfilename) is set to ".htaccess":

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

By default, it's already ".htaccess" but it could have been changed.

Finally, try adding some gibberish to the top of your htaccess file (like "ashdakjhfdksjfhds"), if you get a 500 internal server error, that means your htaccess file is being read and the problem isn't your setup but the contents of the file.